# Create an empty workbook in r

Tags: r, xlconnect

I'd like to create an empty workbook and save as `workbook.xlsx`, so that I can write data into multiple sheets in this workbook in the next step.

I used `loadWorkbook` with package `XLConnect`. Document says:

```
# Load workbook (create if not existing)
loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx", create = TRUE)
```

However, it doesn't work.

```
Error in loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx", create = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (create = TRUE)
```

I also used `createWorkbook` with package `xlsx`. It gives me back a workbook with class `jobjRef`.

```
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
> class(wb)
[1] "jobjRef"
attr(,"package")
[1] "rJava"
```

Where did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try this `detach("package:xlsx", unload=TRUE)` and after that run your code again (i.e. `loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx", create = TRUE)`)

Comment: Thanks, @Miha, it works! Could you perhaps explain a bit why the detach fixed the problem?

Comment: The reason why this happens is because you loaded both libraries:  `XLConnect` and `xlsx`. The priority belongs to the last library loaded, hence, in this example, `xlsx` masks some function of `XLConnect` and cause the error.

Comment: Thanks, Miha. Got it. XLConnect::loadWorkbook also works then.

Comment: I'm glad to help.